# Excel VBA: Find a value in Worksheet, offset column to find same value

Tags: vba, excel

Apologies for my newbishness but I am experiencing a bit of an issue regarding some excel vba code I made. It is meant to clean an excel sheet that has hundreds of entries.

The format is always the same, and columns D, E, and F will sometimes have the same word in all three of them (the word purge). When this is the case, I want that row deleted.

I have tried to use define a my range as D, and using the .Find feature search for my item in question. Then from there offset Find offset Find.

Alas, my program has converted from telling me I am coding wrong to simply running (freezing) forever with no results. I will post my code so that maybe my situation is more clear.

P.S.
If someone can help me fix my code, and also explain what I did wrong and why, it would be much appreciated!

Thank you, all!

```
    Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim strFind As String
    Dim SrchRng
    Dim x As Range
    Dim y
    Dim z



    'searches directory for any and all excel files
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show Then
        strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "No folder selected!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub

        End If
        End With

    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    strPath = strPath & "\"
      End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")
    Do While strFile <> ""
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile, AddToMRU:=False)

    For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets
    'end directory search


    'supposed to search column d, offset column +1 in same row, 
    'then do same for a third row.
    'if all three cells contain "PURGE" then delete cell

         Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("D1", 
    ActiveSheet.Range("D65536").End(xlUp))
        Do
            Set x = SrchRng.Find("PURGE", LookIn:=xlValues)
            Set y = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Find("PURGE", LookIn:=xlValues)
            Set z = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Find("PURGE", LookIn:=xlValues)

          If Not x Is Nothing And Not y Is Nothing And Not z Is Nothing Then         x.EntireRow.Delete
            Loop While Not x Is Nothing

            Next
            For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets


            Next wsh

            wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
            strFile = Dir



            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your `Loop While Not x Is Nothing` doesn't do anything. If it starts out with *not x is nothing* then it is going to try and run forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this. This uses `FindNext` and `Offset` (not entirely sure why you were trying to use `Find` on one cell) This finds the value `PURGE` and if the two cells next to it are also `PURGE` it then deletes the row. If not it carries on going.

Also this line `Do While strFile <> ""` needs a `Loop` at some point although not sure where you wanted it.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim strPath As String, strFile As String, strFind As String, firstAddress As String
    Dim x As Range, y As Range, z As Range
    Dim DelRng As Range


    'searches directory for any and all excel files
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show Then
            strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder selected!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        strPath = strPath & "\"
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        ' Stops xlsm files on Open event
        .EnableEvents = False
        ' uncomment to hide any deletion message boxes
        ' .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")

    Do While Len(strFile) > 0

        Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile, AddToMRU:=False)

        For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets
            'end directory search
            'supposed to search column d, offset column +1 in same row,
            'then do same for a third row.
            'if all three cells contain "PURGE" then delete cell

            With wsh.Columns(4)
                Set x = .Find("PURGE", Lookat:=xlPart)
                If Not x Is Nothing Then
                    firstAddress = x.Address
                    Do
                        If InStr(1, x.Offset(0, 1), "purge", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, x.Offset(0, 2), "purge", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                            If DelRng Is Nothing Then
                                Set DelRng = x
                            Else
                                Set DelRng = Union(DelRng, x)
                            End If
                        End If
                        Set x = .FindNext(x)
                    Loop While Not x Is Nothing And x.Address <> firstAddress
                End If
            End With
        Next wsh
        If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete

        wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
        strFile = Dir()
    Loop

    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tom! You have opened my eyes to another way of doing things! What is happening with your new code is this: First I am told that I have a "Do" without "Loop", so I add a loop. 
Next I am not getting expected results, such as it seems rows are not being deleted.
I will see if I can add excel files so it will be more clear.
Thank you again!

Comment: No problem :). You may run into issues with the Range that you've selected as this will change whilst you Delete rows. To avoid this I'd just select the whole of column D. To do this replace: `With wsh.Range("D1", wsh.Range("D65536").End(xlUp))` with `With wsh.Columns(4)` This will select the whole of Column D

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to add a file to this website. I thought I had seen it done before. I will try the edit you suggested and see if it helps me out!

Comment: So yes, I see what the code is trying to do. However I am still a little bit confused as I am not getting any result at all. In theory the code should work. And adding Wend to any part of my code causes it to tell me I have a "Wend without while." Apologies, I am almost there!

Comment: @chrisleepotter Can you give it another go. It should now work

Comment: It almost does. It is telling me that I need to specify an object at the point where it says "Loop While Not x Is Nothing and x.Address <> firstAddress"

At this point, I am thoroughly embarrassed of my persistence in yelling "help me, help me," so I thank you for your time and expect nothing more! I will take the lesson you've taught me and make this hotrod work!

Comment: @chrisleepotter so to explain that. I'd put the `FindNext` statement inside the `If` loop. If it did find a "PURGE" it deleted it and then didn't change it to the next "PURGE" value meaning I'd just deleted the object and then was testing against it. I've now moved this outside of the `If` Condtiion so it will work

Comment: I now see that the debug function says "Set x = .FindNext(x)"  says "x.Address=<object required>

And that makes sense to move the FindNext option out of the If condition, I never though of that before! (I am literally learning this from forums and by trial-and-error)

I am using Excel 2013, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Not currently.
I am getting a Run-Time error message "Unable to get the FindNext  property of the Range Class.
What I see if I browse the code in debugger mode is that the "firstAddress = x.Address" returns a firstAddress, yet the x.Address is not an object

Comment: ok I think this is due to the fact that we've deleted `x`. I've just updated it again. This should also be faster (especially if you have lots of rows to delete) as it does the delete in one hit. Sorry it's difficult to write something 100% error proof when you don't have anything to test on

Comment: Hmm....You have a point. Is it possible for me to send you a file in a pm?
I am now getting a message that says "invalid procedure or call argument"

 I personally have moved to a blank excel file which has the word "purge" written across a solid block of cells.

Comment: Sure thing upload it to google drive, dropbox etc. and share the url

Comment: I have uploaded the files I am using to Google Drive and will post it at the bottom comment. You will see what I eliminated your Union code, it actually IS working. It is just deleting one entry per code run.

Seriously, has anyone appreciated you for your time and dedication recently? I know I sure do. Here is the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4rZ9ZqoU0tU3M3bzQydTlvbzA

Comment: It should all be working now. Copy and paste the entire code block into your file and replace all your code. No problem. If you've got anymore issues let me know. If it has answered everything click on the tick on the left of the answer :)

Comment: It is working perfectly. By the way, what was making it only loop once and then quit?

Comment: And by the way, thanks a million! If I could pay you I would!
As it is, you have been great Tom. Please enjoy your place of good repute.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally write the formula in excel that would figure out if a row needs to be deleted or not. (do any of the columns for the row contain the word you are looking for). Once I know the formula work correctly I would add it to the file using vba in the last column.

Once the formula in the last column I would sort this row and deleted any of the rows I need. Then delete the new column and save the file.